# PHP foreach with multidimensional array not printing all values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a very simple multidimensional array and some PHP code. The code should print the `p_id` values, but it does not do it. Do I really have to add one foreach more or is there other ways?

And here is the array:

```
Array (
  [2764] => Array (
    [status] => 0

    [0] => Array (
      [p_id] => 2895
    )

    [1] => Array (
      [p_id] => 1468
    )
  )

  [5974] => Array (
    [status] => 0

    [0] => Array (
      [p_id] => 145
    )

    [1] => Array (
      [p_id] => 756
    )
  )
)
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
foreach($arr as $innerArray)
  foreach($innerArray as $key => $value)
    echo $key . "=>" . $value . "<br>";
```

It prints:

```
status=>0
0=>Array
1=>Array
status=>0
0=>Array
1=>Array
```

Comment: What does this code do? What's the problem?

Comment: You can use [`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) to print all the keys and values contained in the array. But it doesn't reveal the internal structure of the array and it's not very helpful.

Comment: You have three-dimensional array in your example, but you loop through only two dimensions.

Comment: @GinoPane OK. And I just have to add one foreach more?

Comment: No, you will also have to check whether the key on the second level is `status` or not, resp. whether the element on the second level is an array or not. (And you don't need an extra foreach loop - you know already that the arrays on the last level only have one element with key `p_id`, assuming the data structure is consistent.)

Comment: @CBroe Great, I see. Solved.

Comment: The array is 3 levels deep, the code iterates only the outer 2 levels. Some of the objects on level 2 are arrays (they produce the 3rd level) and that's the reason the code prints `Array`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This simple call to [`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) produces the output requested in the question:

```
array_walk_recursive(
    $arr, 
    function ($value, $key) {
        echo $key . "=>" . $value . "<br>";
    }
);
```

But it doesn't make much sense as the output mixes the values of `status` with the values of `p_id`.

I would go for a more structured display using the original code with a little more meaning for the names of the variables:

```
foreach ($arr as $catId => $catInfo) {
    // Category ID and details; use other names if I'm wrong
    printf("Category: %d (status: %s)\n", $catId, $catInfo['status'] ? 'active' : 'inactive');
    foreach ($catInfo as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == 'status') {
            // Ignore the status; it was already displayed
            continue;
        }

        foreach ($value as $prodInfo) {
            printf("    Product ID: %d\n", $prodInfo['p_id']);
        }
    }
}
```

---

The structure of the input array tells me you should first fix the code that generates it. It should group all the products (the values that are now indexed by numeric keys) into a single array. It should look like this:

```
$input = array(
    '2764' => array(
        'status' => 0,
        'products' => array(
            2895 => array(
                'p_id' => 2895,
                'name' => 'product #1',
                // more product details here, if needd
            ),
            1468 => array(
                'p_id' => 1468,
                'name' => 'product #2',
            ),
            // more products here
        ),
    // more categories here
),
```

Then the code that prints it will look like this:

```
foreach ($arr as $catId => $catInfo) {
    // Category ID and details; use other names if I'm wrong
    printf("Category: %d (status: %s)\n", $catId, $catInfo['status'] ? 'active' : 'inactive');
    foreach ($catInfo['products'] as $prodInfo) {
        printf("    %s (ID: %d)\n", $prodInfo['name'], $prodInfo['p_id']);
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($arr as $a => $a_value)
{
    echo $a . '<br>'; 
    foreach($a_value as $av_arr => $av)
    {
        if(!is_array($av)) 
        {
            echo $av_arr . '=>' . $av . '<br>'; 
        }
        else
        {
            foreach($av as $inner_av => $inner_av_val)
            {
                echo $inner_av . '=>' . $inner_av_val . '<br>'; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use a recursive function:

```
function printIds($arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
        if (is_array($val) && array_key_exists("p_id", $val)) {
            echo $val["p_id"]."\n";
        } elseif(is_array($val)) {
            printIds($val);
        }
    }
}
```

Working example:

```
$arr = [
    2764 => [
        'status' => 0,
        ['p_id' => 100],
    ],
    4544 => [
        'status' => 0,
        ['p_id' => 100],
    ],
    ['p_id' => 100],
];

function printIds($arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
        if (is_array($val) && array_key_exists("p_id", $val)) {
            echo $val["p_id"]"\n";
        } elseif(is_array($val)) {
            printIds($val);
        }
    }
}

printIds($arr);
```

The function loops all entries of a given array and echo's them out, if they contain an array with a key named "p_id". If it does find a nested array, then it does loop also all child arrays.